# Difference in distribution of multinomial distributions

Tags: r, distributions, multinomial-distribution, group-differences

I have some questions regarding how to analyse catagorical data, summarised as percentages on an individual level.

In the data in question, for each individual we know the fraction of biological measurements belonging to some specific category, but we do not know the total number of measurements for that person. For example, we know that for individual 1, 6% of his/her measurements fell into category A, 17% in category B, 20% in category C, etc, but the number of measurements is unknown and varies from individual to individual. Thus, for each individual we have a vector of proportions of the measurements belonging to that category. As they are proportions, the sum of each such vector is 1.

The data consists of 8 observations from two different groups (making for a total sample size of 16 observations), and we wish to test if there is a difference in the distribution of these distributions between the two groups. That is, do the vectors for group 1 tend to be different from those for group 2?

My questions are as follows.

1. Can this be thought of as a multinominal distribution problem, where we wish to compare two multinomial distributions? These distributions then being estimated as the (normalised) average of the corresponding vectors for each individual.
2. If yes to 1), then what is a good test to test such differences?
3. If no to 1), what are alternative ways of analysing the question at hand?

Below I present a simulated dataset that looks structurally similar to what I have at hand (but with numbers here rounded for illustrative purposes only).

```
set.seed(23478) 
n <- 16 
MyData <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=n))
for(i in 1:n){
  MyData[i, ] <- runif(5, 0, 1)
  MyData[i, ] <- round(MyData[i, ] / sum(MyData[i, ]), digits=2)
  MyData[i, 1] <- 1 - sum(MyData[i, -1])
}
MyData <- data.frame(1:n, MyData, rep(c(1,2), each=n/2))
colnames(MyData) <- c("ID", paste("Category", LETTERS[1:5]), c("Group"))
MyData
```

Comment: This is a great question, and something I'm also looking to answer. Did you find a good solution to this?